# Rails 5 - Preserve :js format while redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a situation where:

1. Browser submits a JS format request to the server.
2. The server action redirects to another server action.
3. The second action renders javascript in a `.js.erb` file.

Despite trying a number of approaches, Rails 5 renders the .js.erb literally, showing me the actual code in the view.

How can one get a Rails `redirect_to` to happen in JS format so the js.erb file is run properly?

In Rails 4.2, **this works**:

```
redirect_to custom_data_path(...), format: 'js'
```

In Rails 5.2, I've tried:

```
# 1
redirect_to custom_data_path(...), format: 'js'

# 2
redirect_to custom_data_path(...), format: :js

# 3
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { redirect_to custom_data_path(...) }
end

# 4
request.format = :js
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { redirect_to custom_data_path(...) }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem where my format (json) was not preserved while redirecting

I solved it with (Rails 5):

> redirect_to _path(, params: request.query_parameters.merge(format: params[:format]))

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a concept or "redirect" for js requests. You can always render a script that does a request to the "redirected" url you want.

Instead of

```
format.js { redirect_to custom_data_path(...) }
```

You could have a view for that action with

```
//I'm using query just as an example, but it can be done with vanilla javascript o any js framework
$.getScript('<%= custom_data_path -%>');
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the `format: :js` as an option for the named route instead of an option for redirect_to method? `custom_data_path(...., format: :js)`. Also, check this https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26279 maybe you have to try that turbolinks option if you use turbolink. Personally, I wouldn't use a redirect with js format, I'm not sure if it's a standard (one thing is that it works and another thing is that it's intented to work that way), I can't find official info about that.

Comment: Moving `format: 'js'` inside the path worked. Thank you!